# Проблема с WinApi

Tags: windows, winapi, ассемблер, masm32

У меня возникла проблема при написании программы на ассемблере MASM, а именно я не понимаю что не так с вызовом Api функций:

1. `FindFirstFile`
2. `FindNextFile`

В общем, я использую поиск по маске `C:\*` передаю это в функцию `FindFirstFile`, сохраняю handle, затем я вызываю `FindNextFile`, затем эта функция ищет директории и файлы, я проверяю `dwFileAttributes` на директорию `10h` и на обычный файл `80h`, если это директория, то я добавляю её к основной маске - `C:\dir\*` и затем передаю в функцию `FindFirstFile` сохраняю handle от неё, затем вызываю уже с сохраненным handle функцию `FindNextFile` и вот тут она мне возвращает `..` вместо имени файла, то есть до этого в `C:\*` она нормально отображала имена папок, то теперь `..` причём она завершается с кодом `ERROR_SUCCESS` то-есть всё нормально. И вот я ничего не могу понять, почему она не выводит мне имена папок/файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две точки это "родительскaя директория", у корня диска ее, естественно, нет. Просто пропускайте этот результат.

P.S. Одна точка - сама директория.